# cannot access /mnt/sdcard/dcim/camera/

Tags: android, image

hi this question is linked to "[how to set nat directory path in android gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19853085/how-to-set-nat-directory-path-in-android-gallery)"  i tried both the methods specified there but when the apk file was loaded on mobile, i keep getting the msg

```
Error!
/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/ directory path is not valid!
Please set the image directory name AppConstant.java class
```

I tried this

```
public static final String PHOTO_ALBUM = "Pictures";
```

where there were some images
and  this,

```
public static final String PHOTO_ALBUM = 
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "/DCIM"+"/Camera/";
```

again there were some images
so whats wrong??

1 more thing..
have added permission to read external source in manifest.java.. am still getting the error..

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="info.androidhive.imageslider"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.imageslider.GridViewActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.imageslider.FullScreenViewActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: add permission `read-ExternalStorage` and write also if you are witing

Comment: In order to read or write files on the external storage, your app must acquire the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE or WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE system permissions.

Comment: do u want to all picture from gallery dude IS it or u just want to reach that path /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/  only coz that path is not contain all pics of gallery

Comment: i just want pics of that folder.. anyhow i tried adding permission.. still got the same error .. @Viswanath

Comment: try to remove last slash, "/Camera" instead of "/Camera/"

Comment: did that too no effect.. @Palejandro

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

`Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM`;

Official Doc :http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_DCIM

Here is a link for more info : Using Android’s external storage effectively and judiciously